# Display cmd output in PyQt4 QTextBrowser (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm using PyQt4.X and Python 3.X

I want to display cmd command output at QTextbrowser, so I used this code

```
    test = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True)
    self.textBrowser.append(test)
```

But it doesn't work, so I changed it like this

```
    test = subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True)
    container = str(test)
    self.textBrowser.append(container)
```

Then, it show result at QTextbrowser, but character almost changed like

```
\xb5\xe5\xb6\xf3\xc0\xcc\xba\xea\
```

How can I get proper result? All cmd command outputs has no-english character.

Comment: try `test.decode()` but you have to find the proper encoding

Comment: thanks a lot. now I find encoding and change it